# .Net MiscHelper LogException error

Tags: .net, crm

I have a client who is implementing an Interactive Intelligence integration to CRM 2011 and has run into an exception that we have been unable to pinpoint it's root cause. Below is the log for this error. Thus far is the only piece of information we have on the error.
Any guidance is greatly appreciated!

> "MiscHelper.LogException :  Top Exception
>   Type=System.ServiceModel.FaultException Source=mscorlib Message=The
>   server was unable to process the request due to an internal error. For
>   more information about the error, either turn on
>   IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute
>   or from the  configuration behavior) on the server in
>   order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on
>   tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework 3.0 SDK documentation and
>   inspect the server trace logs. StackTrace:
>
> Server stack trace:  at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(Message
>   reply, MessageFault fault, String action, MessageVersion version,
>   FaultConverter faultConverter) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime
>   operation, ProxyRpc& rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action,
>   Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
>   Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
>   methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
>   message)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]:  at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg) at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type) at
>   Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.IOrganizationService.RetrieveMultiple(QueryBase
>   query) at
>   Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceProxy.RetrieveMultipleCore(QueryBase
>   query) at
>   Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceProxy.RetrieveMultiple(QueryBase
>   query) at
>   Microsoft.Xrm.Client.Services.OrganizationService.<>c_*DisplayClass22.b*_21(IOrganizationService
>   s) at
>   Microsoft.Xrm.Client.Services.OrganizationService.InnerOrganizationService.UsingService[TResult](Func`2
>   action) at
>   Microsoft.Xrm.Client.Services.OrganizationService.RetrieveMultiple(QueryBase
>   query) at
>   OSV_MSCRM_Integration.Crm2011IntegrationService.GetCallDetailsByANI(String
>   ani, String& extension, String& url, Boolean& multipleResults)
>
> StackTrace: at MiscHelper.LogException(Exception e, Boolean
>   alertException, String prefaceMessage, Boolean
>   overrideExceptionMessage)  at
>   Crm2011IntegrationService.GetCallDetailsByANI(String ani, String&
>   extension, String& url, Boolean& multipleResults)  at
>   .SyncInvokeGetCallDetailsByANI(Object , Object[] , Object[] )  at
>   SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]&
>   outputs)  at DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)  at
>   ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)  at
>   ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage41(MessageRpc& rpc)  at
>   ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(MessageRpc& rpc)  at
>   ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc& rpc)  at
>   ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage3(MessageRpc& rpc)  at
>   ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage2(MessageRpc& rpc)  at
>   ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc& rpc)  at
>   ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage1(MessageRpc& rpc)  at
>   MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)  at
>   ChannelHandler.DispatchAndReleasePump(RequestContext request, Boolean
>   cleanThread, OperationContext currentOperationContext)  at
>   ChannelHandler.HandleRequest(RequestContext request, OperationContext
>   currentOperationContext)  at
>   ChannelHandler.AsyncMessagePump(IAsyncResult result)  at
>   ChannelHandler.OnAsyncReceiveComplete(IAsyncResult result)  at
>   AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(IAsyncResult result)  at
>   AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean completedSynchronously)  at
>   AsyncQueueReader.Set(Item item)  at InputQueue
>   1.EnqueueAndDispatch(Item item, Boolean canDispatchOnThisThread)  at InputQueue    1.EnqueueAndDispatch(T item, Action dequeuedCallback,
>   Boolean canDispatchOnThisThread)  at SingletonChannelAcceptor
>   3.Enqueue(QueueItemType item, Action dequeuedCallback, Boolean canDispatchOnThisThread)  at
>   HttpChannelListener.HttpContextReceived(HttpRequestContext context,
>   Action callback)  at
>   SharedHttpTransportManager.OnGetContextCore(IAsyncResult result)  at
>   SharedHttpTransportManager.OnGetContext(IAsyncResult result)  at
>   AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(IAsyncResult result)  at
>   LazyAsyncResult.Complete(IntPtr userToken)  at
>   LazyAsyncResult.ProtectedInvokeCallback(Object result, IntPtr
>   userToken)  at ListenerAsyncResult.WaitCallback(UInt32 errorCode,
>   UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)  at
>   _IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP) "

Comment: Did you try this: "For more information about the error, either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the configuration behavior) on the server in order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework 3.0 SDK documentation and inspect the server trace logs."

Comment: What you posted is an error that essentially says "We are masking the true error for esoteric compatibility reasons" It's long odds you will get any useful info from this error as is.